# Synchronize javascript calls

Tags: javascript

I have 2 scripts

```
script1 = function() {
    // takes very long time
}

script2 = function() {
    // takes less time
}
```

I want to ensure that script2 should run after script1 is complete.

Comment: So is there a problem with calling `script2()` from the end of `script1()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put your script2 to script1. Or for more general solution make script1 function to receive callback function(script2) and call it.

This is the way of many many jquery async functions

```
script1 = function(callback){
      //takes very long time
      callback();
}


script2 = function(){
      //takes less time
}
...
//call like this
script1(script2);
```

Answer (score 0):

what I did before is to set a global bool variable and only assign it to true in the end in script1, and in script2, check the variable, if it's not true, use setTimeOut to call itself later. I know it sounds not a good solution but that's what I realized I can do.

Comment: Although, this may work, it's generally considered poor practice to poll like this when the traditional callback is adequate in this case.

Comment: thanks for the reply yes i did the same simon but i want to is there any other work around